# flatten a list using GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of students which looks like this:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
{
   new Student(){StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", Grade = "FirstGrade", Marks = 98},
   new Student(){StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", Grade = "SecondGrade", Marks = 92},
   new Student(){StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", Grade = "ThirdGrade", Marks = 95},

   new Student(){StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", Grade = "FirstGrade", Marks = 94},
   new Student(){StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", Grade = "SecondGrade", Marks = 95},
   new Student(){StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", Grade = "ThirdGrade", Marks = 94},

   new Student(){StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", Grade = "FirstGrade", Marks = 91},
   new Student(){StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", Grade = "SecondGrade", Marks = 99},
   new Student(){StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", Grade = "ThirdGrade", Marks = 97},
};
```

I want to convert `students` list to `studentReport` list which looks like this:

```
{ StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Alex", FirstGrade = 98, SecondGrade = 92, ThirdGrade = 95},
{ StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Karen", FirstGrade = 94, SecondGrade = 95, ThirdGrade = 94},
{ StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Nicole", FirstGrade = 91, SecondGrade = 99, ThirdGrade = 97}
```

I was able to achieve that using this:

```
var studentReports = students.GroupBy(student => new { student.StudentId, student.StudentName })
        .Select(group => new Report()
        {
          StudentId = group.Key.StudentId,
          StudentName = group.Key.StudentName,
          FirstGrade = group.Where(student => student.Grade == "FirstGrade").FirstOrDefault().Marks,
          SecondGrade = group.Where(student => student.Grade == "SecondGrade").FirstOrDefault().Marks,
          ThirdGrade = group.Where(student => student.Grade == "ThirdGrade").FirstOrDefault().Marks
        });
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Try doing a group by id, then doing skip/take or direct indexing the grouping for each grade (and the name)

Comment: Just a .GroupBy followed by a .Select

Comment: `group.Where(student => student.Grade == "ThirdGrade").FirstOrDefault().Marks` could be done like `group.FirstOrDefault(student => student.Grade == "ThirdGrade").?Marks` or if you're certain there will always be 3, just use Single instead of FirstOrDefault

Comment: If the data is in memory, then no, this is probably the cleanest approach. If the code works, questions like `Is there a better way` are better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com try posting there